# Change menu button to graphic on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a hamburger menu button: https://jsfiddle.net/sqvwm1dh/

When this button is clicked, I'd like to replace this button with a graphic.

How do I achieve this with my current code. Do I do this in jQuery?

```
$('header').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');
$('#menu-button').on('click', function(){
  var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
  menuItems.toggle();
});


header {
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}

#menu-button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
    top: 30px;
    right:0;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px 22px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* line 500, sass/_layout.scss */
  #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
  }

  /* line 511, sass/_layout.scss */
  #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
  }


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
        test
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: What do you mean with a `graphic` ?

Comment: Apologies. I mean like (say) http://placehold.it/40x40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

Then in your CSS add a style for your `#menu-button` with the `.active` class and set for instance a background image. Or do something else.

Comment: Thank you, Rens! I will try in a jsfiddle right now :)

Comment: No problem, have fun with the rest of your responsive design.